# Get the JsonResult in ASP.net Function

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-2

How can I get the result of a method that return a JsonResult and cast into string.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult AnalyseNbPayment(DateTime dt, DateTime dt2,int FrequencyID) {

            if (FrequencyID == ApplConfig.Frequency.WEEKLY) {
                return Json(new  { val = GetNbWeek(dt, dt2) });
            }
            else if (FrequencyID == ApplConfig.Frequency.MONTHLY) {
                return Json(new  { val =GetDateDiffInMonth(dt, dt2) });
            }
            else if (FrequencyID == ApplConfig.Frequency.QUARTELY) {
                   return Json(new  { val = GetQuarterLy(dt, dt2) });
            }
            else if (FrequencyID == ApplConfig.Frequency.BI_MONTLY) {
               return Json(new  { val = GetBiMontlhy(dt, dt2) });
            }
            else if(FrequencyID == ApplConfig.Frequency.YEARLY)
            {
                return Json(new { val = GetNbYear(dt, dt2) });
            }

            return Json(new { val =0 });
        }
```

I want to call my method like this

```
string MyValue = AnalyseNbPayment(Convert.ToDateTime(ViewModel.oRent.DateFrom), Convert.ToDateTime(ViewModel.oRent.DateTo), Convert.ToInt32(oLease.FrequencyID)).val.ToString(); <br />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var jsonResult = AnalyseNbPayment();
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(jsonResult.Data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using the `dynamic` type to retrieve the info. In your case it would be (make sure to have .Data at the end of the assignment):

```
dynamic MyValue = AnalyseNbPayment(Convert.ToDateTime(ViewModel.oRent.DateFrom), Convert.ToDateTime(ViewModel.oRent.DateTo), Convert.ToInt32(oLease.FrequencyID)).Data;
```

Then you could simply do the following:

```
//the var val will be the appropriate data type...in your case it looks like int so .ToString() will get you what you want.
var result = MyValue.val.ToString();
```

The dynamic type is some crazy stuff!